# Trying to understand Distributed Counter in Firebase Extensions

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

**Based on this rule**

[image]

I created a collection like this

```
Test_Collection (Collection)
|
--- JyhaBOdreMTXM4QC4N8c (Document)
    |
    --- Likes (Number Field) -> Default value is 0
```

And I create a function on the client-side to increase the `Likes` field every 250ms for 2 minutes, After that, I run the app on 4 emulators at the same time.

After 2 minutes the `Likes` field became 1920 instead of 0, How?

```
4 Likes will increase in the Likes field every 1 second
4 * 120 seconds (2 minutes) = 480 Likes
480 * 4 (4 emulators) = 1920 Likes
```

1. The first question is the rule above in the image incorrect?
2. The second question is what are the benefits of [Distributed
   Counter](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-counter)? Because everything works well why we need this
   [extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-counter)?

> I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sA4tkIZ_C5E)

Comment: Hi @ofTHIS, welcome to Stack! Can you please add an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your function to see what exactly you tried? Thanks